# Switch statements in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am writing a program in C with switch statements and I was wondering if the compiler will accept a statement such as

```
case !('a'):
```

I couldn't find any programs online that used the `!` with a switch statement.

Comment: Use an `if` statement instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, sorry, not in the way that you intend (negating the whole logical expression rather than one of its components). But you can use the `default` clause to match anything that wasn't matched by a `case`.

Answer (score 12):

Did you actually try it?

Well, I did (gcc on Mac OS X).

! is the logical negation operator, and !(x) returns 1 for an x of 0, and 0 for anything else.
`'a'` has a value which is known at compile-time, so the compiler evaluates `!('a')` to 0. So

```
case !('a'):
```

is the equivalent of

```
case 0 :
```

It doesn't even generate a compiler error, and runs fine.

I take it that's not what you want to do, though, and rather want a case that will catch all values except 'a', rather than the single value 0. Sorry but switch-case statements don't work that way. The expression following the `case` keyword has to be a value known to the compiler.

Comment: +1! I believe this is the only answer that is actually describing what's going on behind the scenes. This is important since it's hard to tell whether or not the OP is making a distinction between `!` and `!=` :)

Answer (score 1):

Each case condition has an int as its conditional value.  A character is taken to be a special case of an int.  Using the NOT operator has no meaning in a case statement.

Joe's answer is the best one.